# Change in SD when you add funds in a portfolio of VC funds

Tags: distributions

I would like to measure by how much the standard deviation decrease when I add funds in a VC fund portfolio. 
Lets supose I have the returns obtained by 400 VC funds. With that information I can estimate the mean and the SD.
If want to prove that, as expected, SD decrease when you add more funds. However, at some point the change is marginal (normally around 20 to 30 funds). Any idea of how can I estimate the change for 1 fund, 5 funds, 10 funds, 15, funds, 20 funds, 25 funds and 30 funds?). I do not know how to do it in excel (I guess it could be done with monte carlo)..many thanks

Answer (score 0):

VC = Venture Capital?

It sounds like what you are doing is trying to build (and measure) a diversified portfolio of VC funds.  If so, one thing you are going to need is the correlations, because the stdev of the portfolio is going to be a function of the stdev of each component taking into account their correlation/covariance.

And a word of caution here.  If you are looking at VC funds, you might need to be a bit careful.  If you were looking at broadly diversified stock funds, the returns inside the fund would have something along the lines of a normal distribution (lots to quibble about there, too, but not as bad).

But VC funds themselves have an odd shape, often.  There is the old saying that the difference between VC and other investing is that you are a success in VC if you make 10 investments, 7 go bankrupt with no value, 2 go bankrupt but you can sell some patents for a bit, and one is a big hit.  Thereforethe mean and stdev - and an assumption of normality - is probably wrong, because the underlying distribution is probably more Poisson-like, and you would need to be careful in going through the math to add Poissons that are correlated.

I suspect this is going to be easiest via Monte Carlo, but here is some info that might prove useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244989/correlated-poisson-distribution